# Python and read text file that contains lists with strings and numbers

Tags: python, text-files

This is a similar question to many but not quite the same.  I have a text file that has about 400,000 lines of text.  Each line is essentially a list.  For example it looks like `[ 'a','b',1,2,'c',3,'d and , e string', 45]`

I can read each line of the text file with the following code:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

The problem is that each line is read as a string.  I would like to get each item of the list.  So i thought i would do (for each line):

```
content[line].split(',')
```

This almost works, but i run into a problem.  Many times in my text file i have a string in the list that has a comma in it (from above i had 'd and , e string').  I don't want this string split up but want it as one item.

If this doesn't make since I want to take the line from my text file `[ 'a','b',1,2,'c',3,'d and , e string', 45]` and i want 8 separate elements

```
'a'
'b'
1 
2
'c'
3
'd and , e string'
45
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a duplicate of lots of `ast.literal_eval` questions, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-list-to-list-in-python).

Comment: I have no idea how i missed that!  Thanks for pointing it out -- worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) right

```
from ast import literal_eval

# use generator 
# instead of allocating 
# 400 000 lists at a time
your_lists = (literal_eval(s) for s in open('filename.txt'))
```